# Method to modify images uploaded in SE question that are hosted on imgur

Tags: discussion, support, images, imgur, uploader

Is there a way to modify images that you have posted in a question?  Say I posted the following image:

[image: Sample image]

Now later, I realize I have put "blah blah this is totally a password" out for the internets to see.  Can my SE account be associated to my imgur account to replace the uploaded image, or to crop or blur the offending material?  Or by some other means?

There is the option of uploading a new image all together and replacing it in the question itself, but the old image URL would still be visible in the question history.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you have an issue with an old image that should be removed for security purposes, you can flag it for attention and a CM can remove the version from the history, I believe... but if it's a password, certainly the easiest option would be to simply change it to something else? I don't believe there is a good reason to make this user-controlled.